# 3DES CFB vs CFB8 modes

Tags: 3des, cfb

What is the main difference between CFB and CFB8 modes in 3DES?  Is it only a change in block size from standard 8 byte to 1 byte when doing 3des and XOR? I cant find any pseudocode for this CFB8 mode?  any pointers?

Comment: see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85727/what-is-the-segment-size-when-using-cipher-feedback-cfb-chaining-mode/85741

Comment: @RichieFrame perfect!  Just what I needed to know on the shift register implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between CFB-1(CFB) and CFB-8 is the **size of shifting**.
To understand this - 
$C_i = top_x(res_{i-1})\oplus P_i$
$res_0 = Enc_k(IV)$
$res_{i} = Enc_k(shift_x(res_{i-1}\oplus P_{i-1}))$
$P_i = top_x(res_{i-1})\oplus C_i$
Note that in order to decrypt $C_i$, you will need $P_{i-1}$ which can only be found by decrypting $C_{i-1}$. Hence, this cannot be parallelized.
Here $x$ is the shift size which is 1 in CFB-1 and 8 in CFB-8.